New Electrical Services 400 Amp with main Distribution panel -got high voltage?
I install new service 400 Amp Single Phase with distribution panel and I receive 130 Volts on each leg. Can someone can explain why?
I got check by ComEd utility Co. According to them everything is ok on their site.
I get same volage reading before my equipment and after.
I did this for 30 years and never run in to this situation.
Can someone can help?
Thank you

120 volts is the standard, but there is +/- 10(?)% range that is allowed.  Not exactly sure about the 10% but close.

Maybe test equipment needs calibration?  If the utility is not alarmed, I would not be.

"According to them everything is ok" is an unscientific response to a very specific question.  Does that mean "130V is ok" or does it mean "We read under 126" ?  Can you  sanity-check your meter at a few sites far away from your home and from each other?  Or buy a new one, or have it professionally calibrated, if in fact this is your profession.   BTW, 130V is not widely regarded as OK ... if they say it is, it might mean they don't like the cost of fixing it.

Stretching things for an answer but it might also mean you have a very long service cable and this is how they provision it? 130 no-load? Some utility transformers have switches or taps to compensate for problems like long runs.  130 is high even for that, I think, but this is far away from my expertise.

@crip659 Just fyi The actual NEMA/ANSI Standard is +/-5% at service, resulting in +5/-10% at point of utilization to accommodate the 5% max permissible voltage drop by customer distribution on load side of service.

Check the battery in your meter. In many inexpensive multimeters a low battery can result in higher-than-expected voltage readings.

I would continue to harass ComEd, it is clearly above 127v, the maximum allowed by ANSI C84.1-2020.
Range A: Range A provides the normally expected voltage tolerance on the utility supply for a given voltage class. Variations outside the range should be infrequent. The utilization equipment (loads) are expected to function and provide full satisfactory performance for range A voltage tolerance.
Range B: Range B provides voltage tolerances above and below range A limits that necessarily result from practical design and operating conditions on supply or user systems or both. These conditions should be limited in extent, frequency and duration. When these variations occur, measures should be taken within a reasonable time frame to get back to range A.


Unfortunately a full copy of C84.1 is $163.00!

10' from the transformer-this is only explanation for me. They boost up for others for voltage drop . Everything is new, I change electric oven/stove ,big ass fan sometimes shots off, fry coffee maker ,LED shots of from switch-working on dimmer have way ,New house with separate neutrals on all circuits . why they call 110-120 /220/240

why they call 110-120 /220/240 There were/are various supply and manufacturer standards worldwide, even now see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country#Table_of_mains_voltages,_frequencies,_and_plugs
